# Backbone: Shared Model between Collections -- updated Collection reference?

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model

everyone!  This may be an architectural no-no, but I'd like to get some feedback on how to go about fixing this issue.

Say that I have one Model shared between two or more Collections, and from the context of the Model, I'd like to get certain instance fields of the containing Collection *dynamically*.  Now, I know that I can access the containing Collection via `model.collection` and that I can modify the reference by passing in `{collection: blahCollection}` options in the Model constructor.  However, that doesn't help my current case since Backbone does premature optimization in Collection#set and just merges Model attributes but doesn't update any instance fields.

Here's an example that illustrates my issue.

```
var model, collection1, collection2;

model = new Backbone.Model();
collection1 = new Backbone.Collection();
collection1.title = 'collection1';
collection2 = new Backbone.Collection();
collection2.title = 'collection2';

// Add the Model to the first Collection
collection1.add(model);
console.log(model.collection.title); // prints 'collection1' as intended
collection2.add(model);
console.log(model.collection.title); // still prints 'collection1'
```

I've thought of a couple of workarounds for this, but none of them seems particularly great.

1. Force the creation of a new Model in each Collection.  I'd have to add a `collection1_` or `collection2_` prefix to each Model id or something similar to that, but that's terrible for updates.
2. Add an attribute on each Model that's manually changed in Collection#set, which seems equally terrible.
3. Keep track of a global `collectionTitle` that changes whenever we need to reference the active Collection...but that seems like spaghetti bookkeeping.

I guess my question is: Is there any way I can get the containing Collection that last added the Model *from the context of the Model*?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could override `Collection.add` or `Collection.set` to reassign the models' collection to reflect the latest `add` operation.

Something like

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    add: function() {
        var ms = Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.apply(this, arguments);

        _.each(ms, function(m) {
            ms.collection = this;
        }, this);

        return ms;
    }
});

model = new Backbone.Model();
collection1 = new C();
collection1.title = 'collection1';
collection2 = new C();
collection2.title = 'collection2';

collection1.add(model);
console.log(model.collection.title);
collection2.add(model);
console.log(model.collection.title);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/frkc3a51/

Comment: @stephen Out of curiosity, did that help or did I misunderstand your question?